# How do I install .NET Framework upgrades on Server Core?

Tags: .net, azure-service-fabric, server-core

I've a number of Server Core VMs on Azure, for a Service Fabric cluster. They run the 2016-Datacenter-Server-Core image.

The VMs have .NET Framework 4.6.2 installed by default. How can I upgrade the framework, e.g. to 4.7.1?

KB4033393 is not available via Windows Update. I've tried manually downloading the KB and installing it:

```
wget http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/ftpk/2017/11/windows10.0-kb4033393-x64_2a569b5822abf71975ca7f9b0c8dd3791f326f40.msu -UseBasicParsing -OutFile windows10.0-kb4033393-x64_2a569b5822abf71975ca7f9b0c8dd3791f326f40.msu
wusa .\windows10.0-kb4033393-x64_2a569b5822abf71975ca7f9b0c8dd3791f326f40.msu
```

After accepting the license, it simply says:

> The following updates were not installed:
>
> Update for Windows (KB4033393)

Comment: Try this: https://serverfault.com/questions/899192/unable-to-install-net-framework-4-7-1-on-server-core-installation-windows-server

Comment: @PeterBons That's the problem, the KB is not offered via Windows Update.

Comment: Hmm, an .msu file whose name starts with "windows10" does not sound like an ideal match for server core.  [Try this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56116).  Do post this at serverfault.com if that did not help or you don't like trying.

Comment: @HansPassant the [KB download page](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4033393) lists Windows Server 2016 as a supported product, I assumed that includes Server Core. Executing that installer has worked, thanks! I'll post an answer with details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The offline installer [linked by Hans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50173815/how-do-i-install-net-framework-upgrades-on-server-core#comment87369555_50173815) works.

1. Navigate to the offline installer download page, e.g. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56116
2. Get the URL for the download by copying it from the *click here to download manually* link, e.g. https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/E/6/9E63300C-0941-4B45-A0EC-0008F96DD480/NDP471-KB4033342-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe
3. Download and install the update with PowerShell:

   ```
   wget https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/E/6/9E63300C-0941-4B45-A0EC-0008F96DD480/NDP471-KB4033342-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe -UseBasicParsing -OutFile NDP471-KB4033342-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe
   .\NDP471-KB4033342-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe /q /norestart
   ```

You can use the task manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> when using RDP) to know when the installer is finished. You can verify the installation by listing version information with `Get-ChildItem "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\"`, or by running `systeminfo` which should list the relevant KB (e.g. KB4033393) under *Hotfixe(s)*.

You can also exclude the `/norestart` parameter, the server will reboot automatically then after installation has finished.